# Rendering output of report function from report package to knitr

Tags: r, latex, report, knitr

I want to render the output of `report` function from `report` R package into `.Rnw` (using `knitr`) for `pdf format` output. However, it is not working as expected.

```
library(report)
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
report(model)
We fitted a linear model (estimated using OLS) to predict Sepal.Length with Species (formula: Sepal.Length ~ Species). The model explains a statistically significant and substantial proportion of variance (R2 = 0.62, F(2, 147) = 119.26, p < .001, adj. R2 = 0.61). The model's intercept, corresponding to Species = setosa, is at 5.01 (95% CI [4.86, 5.15], t(147) = 68.76, p < .001). Within this model:

  - The effect of Species [versicolor] is statistically significant and positive (beta = 0.93, 95% CI [0.73, 1.13], t(147) = 9.03, p < .001; Std. beta = 1.12, 95% CI [0.88, 1.37])
  - The effect of Species [virginica] is statistically significant and positive (beta = 1.58, 95% CI [1.38, 1.79], t(147) = 15.37, p < .001; Std. beta = 1.91, 95% CI [1.66, 2.16])

Standardized parameters were obtained by fitting the model on a standardized version of the dataset.
```

Using `report(model)` along with `results = 'asis'` does not work properly since the output contains special character `%`. Using `results = 'markup'` does not respect the page width.

I tried `kable(report(model))`, but throws the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, which, value = "") : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

**Package Information**

```
packageVersion("report")
[1] ‘0.3.0’
```

**Edited**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, width = 80)
@

<<chunk1>>=
library(report)
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
report(model)
@

\end{document}
```

**Editted** (2021-06-22)

It is a [bug](https://github.com/easystats/report/issues/190).

Answer (score 1):

`htmltools::tagList()` might be what you're looking for:

````
```{r}
library(report)
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
htmltools::tagList(report(model))
```
````

[image]

However, `results='asis'` seems to better respect line breaks:

````
```{r,results='asis'}
library(report)
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
report(model)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Waldi for your answer. Would appreciate it if you can give a solution which can respect the line breaks. Please compare the out of `tagList(report(model))` with `report(model)` .

Comment: @MYaseen208, I see what you mean :-). What happened on your side with `results='asis'`, it seems to work as expected on my computer, see my edit.

Comment: I guess this works only `.Rmd` not in `.Rnw`.

Comment: did you try `knitr::asis_output(report(model))` in the rnw chunck? If it doesn't work,, a MRE with `.Rnw` would be helpful.

Comment: Please @Waldi see my edits for an example of `.Rnw`.

Comment: Thanks. Having troubles making the `.Rnw` work probably due to my Tinytex installation : missing some `.sty` packages.